# Indexing of single and multiple Psalms in bibleref / bibleref-german

Tags: makeindex, bibleref

In scholarship, a single reference to a Psalm is abbreviated with "Ps" (for "Psalm"), while references to several Psalms are abbreviated as "Pss" ("Psalms").

The `bibleref-german` package does accommodate for that by printing "Pss" when the abbreviation "Ps" is used, and by defining a new book "Psalm", for which the abbreviation "Ps" is printed.

This is how the book is defined in `bibleref-german.sty`:

```
\def\br@Psalm{Ps\BRperiod}%
\def\br@Psalms{Pss\BRperiod}%
```

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[RGG]{bibleref-german}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Single psalm reference: \ibibleverse{Psalm}(23:1)

Multiple psalm references: \ibibleverse{Ps}(119:105); \ibiblechvs{Ps}(121:2)

\printindex
\end{document}
```

It looks like this in the rendered text:

```
Single psalm reference: Ps 23,1

Multiple psalm references: Pss 119,105; 121,2
```

The problem is that this differentiation is then also made in the index, i.e. there are two different entries for "Ps" and "Pss" in the index:

[image: Bibleref index for Psalms]

I want to differentiate in the text between "Ps" and "Pss", but have all references listed under "Pss" in the index (or "Ps", for that matter). How do I achieve that the references to `Ps` as well as the references to `Psalm` are both mapped to `Pss` in the index?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure how to fix `bibref` (or `bibref-german`), so what I did is replace the book name in the `*.idx` file before it is processed by `makeindex`.

First of all, I need to specify a mapping in which "Ps" and "Pss" have the same order:

```
[...]
\biblerefmap{Ps}{23} 
\biblerefmap{Pss}{23} 
[...]
```

Then, after compiling the tex file and before creating the index, I need to do a string replacement (for instance, by using `sed`,  [see alternatives here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command)):

```
pdflatex file.tex
sed -i "s/BRbooktitlestyle {Pss}/BRbooktitlestyle {Ps}/g" file.idx
makeindex file.idx
pdflatex file.tex
```